# json parse multiple objects php

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I created multiple json object array namely plans and products. Please help me to iterate values of products from products array.

```
{
  "plans": [
    "silver",
    {
        "plan_name": "Silver Plan",
        "products": ["A", "B"],
        "price": "1000"
    },
    "gold",
    {
        "plan_name": "Gold Plan",
        "products": ["A", "B"],
        "price": "2000"
    }
 ],
"products": [
    "A",
    {
        "product_name": "Plan A",
        "price": "100"
    },

    "B",
    {
        "product_name": "Plan B",
        "price": "100"
    },
    "C",
    {
        "product_name": "Plan C",
        "price": "100"
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: first json_decode($products), then use foreach($products as $key=>$value){ //echo products[$key]['product_name'];   }

Comment: @Deepak: `json_decode($product)` will return a stdObject, use `json_decode($product, true)` to return an array

Comment: i need to iterate plans first and take corresponding values of products from product json

Comment: can you please post your resultant array format

Comment: I need below format in output
 
 Silver 
   Silver Plan ( From Plan array )
   Product Name : Plan A ( From Products array)
   Product Price : 100
   Product Name : Plan B
   Product Price : 100
   
 Gold 
   Gold Plan ( From Plan array )
   Product Name : Plan A ( From Products array)
   Product Price : 100
   Product Name : Plan B
   Product Price : 100

Comment: Json Format : {
 "plans": [
  "silver",
  {
   "plan_name": "Silver Plan",
   "products": ["A", "B"],
   "price": "1000"
  },
  "gold",
  {
   "plan_name": "Gold Plan",
   "products": ["A", "B"],
   "price": "2000"
  }
 ],
 "products": [
  "A",
  {
   "product_name": "Plan A",
   "price": "100"
  },

  "B",
  {
   "product_name": "Plan B",
   "price": "100"
  },
  "C",
  {
   "product_name": "Plan C",
   "price": "100"
  }
 ]
}

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check this. First, I have separated the `products` then iterate the products array separately.

```
      <?php
  $str = '{ "plans": [ "silver", { "plan_name": "Silver Plan", "products": ["A", "B"], "price": "1000" }, "gold", { "plan_name": "Gold Plan", "products": ["A", "B"], "price": "2000" } ], "products": [ "A", { "product_name": "Plan A", "price": "100" },
      "B",
      {
          "product_name": "Plan B",
          "price": "100"
      },
      "C",
      {
          "product_name": "Plan C",
          "price": "100"
      }
  ]
  }';
  $products = json_decode($str);
  // print_r($products);
  foreach($products as $key=>$value)
  {

      if($key=='products')
      {
        foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
          if(!is_object($value1))
          echo $value1 . '<br>';//will echo A,B,C
          if(is_object($value1))
          {
            foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
              echo $value2 . '<br>';//Will echo product_name and price
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
```

**Result**

```
A
Plan A
100
B
Plan B
100
C
Plan C
100
```

Comment: Silver Plan
Plan A
100
Plan B
100


Gold Plan
Plan A
100
Plan B
100

Comment: As mentioned in your question ***I created multiple json object array namely plans and products. help in iterate values of products from products array.*** I followed this

Comment: I suggest you ask another question. This post answers your question